# Can't get to login screen

Tags: grub2

Ubuntu 12.04 has worked fine for a long time. After an update I turned the computer off, and when I turned it on the next day I got this screen:

> GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.9
>   Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-40-generic
>   Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-40-generic (recovery mode)
>   Previous Linux version
>   Memory test (memtest86+)
>   Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
>
> Press enter to boot selected OS

I don't see 12.04, my operating system, so I don't know what to select.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu reverted to GNU GRUB beta version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906842/ubuntu-reverted-to-gnu-grub-beta-version)

Answer (score 0):

Just from that description, I don't see any indication that there's something wrong with your boot configuration. Therefore, you shouldn't have to do what @Suhaib suggests.

The "regular" Ubuntu selection is "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-40-generic". This is probably what you want.

Comment: ya, I thought it is 12.10 xD