# Ubuntu reverted to GNU GRUB beta version

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed BleachBit on Ubuntu 16.04 using an old (Vista generation) 64-bit PC.
I do not understand what I am looking at after reboot. The screen shows the following:

```
                   GNU GRUB Version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9

*Ubuntu (Generic)
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory Test (memtest86+)
Memory Test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux (Upstart)
Ubuntu, with Linux (Recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-71-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux (Upstart)
Ubuntu, with Linux (Recovery mode)
```

Have I unknowingly erased the whole Ubuntu 16.04? If so, why stop there? Please advise.

Comment: What you see looks normal (although I guess you are not used to seeing GRUB so maybe something is wrong). What happens when you wait or press enter?

Answer (score 2):

What you see looks like a normal GRUB boot menu. The entries listed in the boot menu allow you to select the default Ubuntu kernel or to choose between two Linux kernels 4.4.0-71-generic and 4.4.0-72-generic and boot with the selected kernel. If you use the ↑ and ↓ keys to select the default option marked by an asterisk (Ubuntu (Generic)) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot from it, your computer should boot into Ubuntu with the default kernel as usual.

If you run `apt policy grub2-common` in Ubuntu 16.04, you should get the following result.

```
grub2-common:
  Installed: 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9
  Candidate: 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9
```

It shows the same result as this first line on the GRUB menu screen in your question, and everything on your GRUB screen is normal like it should be including the Advanced options for selecting options of booting from different recently installed Linux kernel versions.

If you run `uname -a` the results should show that you are using the 4.4.0-72-generic Linux kernel, which is the latest version in Ubuntu 16.04, the same as is shown in your GRUB menu screen.

---

Regarding the GRUB menu screen, normally you do not see this screen, and what specific GRUB screen you see depends on whether your system is a single boot or dual boot.

Comment: The command `sudo update-grub` generates a grub2 config file, however **don't run this command** before telling about whether your system is a single boot or dual boot first.

Answer (score 0):

When you run bleach bit there are some options you can check or un-check. The one that concerns us here is whether you ran bleach bit as root. Running almost anything as root provides many more opportunities to corrupt a system. My suggestion is that you click on the recovery mode. If it boots up you should first back up all your data. Next you can try to run an update. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to bring up a terminal.
Type this command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
Now enter your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> . Then sit back and watch the show. when you get back to the command prompt, you will want to close the terminal and reboot. If it works you can now function check and see if your data is all there.

Comment: No evidence that OP can't boot normally. They are just confused about the GRUB version being "beta". And what good would running an update do?